# mirroring animation

Tags: animation, mirror

I want to mirror sword attack animation, now I have sword attack with right hand, but I want dual sword attack animation, What I need is to mirror that animation, when right hand attack will done there must be the same animation keyframes but mirrored so it will slash with left hand.

how can I achieve this in blender? I tried shift + ctrl + v but result was very weird

Comment: please show a screenshot what you have (animation) and what you want to have. Because there can be mirrored a lot. e.g. you can mirror to x-axis, to x and y axis. You can mirror time...and so on.

Comment: @Chris thanks for reply, I have this animation and I want to make dual sword attack, right hand first like in this animation and then left hand attack https://s6.gifyu.com/images/ezgif.com-gif-maker01619184f1b99933.gif

Comment: this animation is available on mixamo com with name "standing melee attack"

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you did not describe how exactly you want to mirror your animation.

But after copying the animation you can do it by opening the graph editor and then select all and right click. Then you will find this menu:

[image]

With these mirror options you should be able to do what you want.

Comment: I tried this but still not working well, here is a animation https://s6.gifyu.com/images/ezgif.com-gif-maker01619184f1b99933.gif